# Code coverage with pytest-based ROS tests

Tags: rostest

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to add code coverage to my pytests, following the instructions from [code_coverage repo](https://github.com/mikeferguson/code_coverage#python-rostest-support), except that I use python3-coverage.

I run my rostest with pytest using the [Pytest integration instructions](https://machinekoder.com/testing-ros-powered-robots-pytest/#:%7E:text=and%20integration%20tests.-,Pytest%20integration,-ROS%20calls%20its)

So I run both prefixed with python3-coverage run -p.  The rostest file looks like:

```
<launch>    
  <node name="config_server" pkg="config_server" type="config_server_node.py"
        launch-prefix="python3-coverage run -p">
  </node>

  <param name="test_module" value="test_config_server.py"/>
  <test test-name="config_server_test" pkg="config_server" type="pytest_runner.py" time-limit="60.0"
        launch-prefix="python3-coverage run -p"/>
</launch>
```

As explained in [the issue I opened on code coverage repo](https://github.com/mikeferguson/code_coverage/issues/40), I'm actually getting a coverage report on screen, but all files are empty!

```
nodes/config_server_node.py              7      0   100%
src/config_server/config_server.py     138      8    94%
```

(see the whole command line output on the issue for details)

Has anyone tried this before and has an example of how to do?

Thanks a lot

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/404820/code-coverage-with-pytest-based-ros-tests/) by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2284 on 2022-08-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My bad: Python code coverage goes to somewhere else

```
Python code coverage html-format: /home/jorge/.ros/htmlcov/index.html.
```

---

Originally posted by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) with karma: 2284 on 2022-08-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0